# How to ask npm what the deltas are between package.json and the latest available?

Tags: npm

I have a package.json in a project I need to maintain, which has versions specified with ~ and or ^ .

How can I find out which of these packages have moved on past the specified major version (caret) or minor version (tilde) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy, just found: `npm outdated` :)